# Separate rows of a character column in R

Tags: r, genius-api

I am using the genius package in R.
The package pulls lyrics by line as characters, and I want to separate the lines into the individual words.

I have this code:

```r
Albums <- bind_rows(TaylorSwift, Fearless, SpeakNow, Red, nineteeneightynine, reputation, Lover, folklore, evermore, Fearless2)

separate_rows(Albums$lyric, sep = " ")
```

solved thanks to greg, didn't know dataframe and column were separate args
Running it returns this error:

> no applicable method for 'separate_rows' applied to an object of class "character"

What do?

Comment: Assuming you're using `?tidyr::separate_rows`, the first argument should be a data frame, and the second argument the column name. `spearate_rows(Albums, lyric, sep = " ")`.

Comment: Rookie mistake. Thanks Greg I'm gonna go get my brain checked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.